# Exposing openshift service to aws public ip

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-ingress

I am running openshift in aws

```
[centos@ip-10-0-0-14 ~]$ oc version
oc v3.6.1+008f2d5
kubernetes v1.6.1+5115d708d7
features: Basic-Auth GSSAPI Kerberos SPNEGO

Server https://ip-10-0-0-14.ec2.internal:8443
openshift v3.6.1+008f2d5
kubernetes v1.6.1+5115d708d7
```

I have one master and two nodes.
How can I expose a service to aws public ip? I can access service internally:

```
links http://blogroute-project-a.router.default.svc.cluster.local
```

How can I expose it to public ip? Is it possible to be done in openshfit web console?
I have tried to follow https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.4/dev_guide/expose_service/expose_internal_ip_service.html but failed.

In command:

oc patch svc blog -p '{"spec":{"externalIPs":["what ip?"]}}'

doc states about ip visible in ifconfig, (but it's not aws public ip).
Which ip should I use, aws public ip, or private ip (eg 10-0-0-14) from aws local network?

Should I use ip of master node? Or of worker? If I have two worker nodes shoudl I write ips of both of them?

Currently there are following routes:

```
[centos@ip-10-0-0-14 ~]$ oc get routes
NAME             HOST/PORT                                                   PATH      SERVICES         PORT       TERMINATION   WILDCARD
blog             blog-project-a.router.default.svc.cluster.local                       blog             8080-tcp                 None
blog-django-py   blog-django-py-project-a.router.default.svc.cluster.local             blog-django-py   8080-tcp                 None
blog2            ec2-3-90-171-97.compute-1.amazonaws.com                     /blog2    blog             8080-tcp                 None
blogroute        blogroute-project-a.router.default.svc.cluster.local                  blog             8080-tcp                 None
```

for following services:

```
[centos@ip-10-0-0-14 ~]$ oc get svc
NAME             CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
blog             172.30.111.64   3.90.171.97   8080/TCP   5d
blog-django-py   172.30.184.15   <none>        8080/TCP   5d
```

Comment: Is it a HTTP service? Have you created a route using ``oc expose svc`` to see if that works? Do you have a public DNS wildcard host record which points at your OpenShift cluster router port so you could access the generated hostname in the route though?

Comment: Graham, thx for comment, yes, it's http service. I can even access it from any of 3 aws centos vms with links text browser. Regarding third sentence in your comment:OMG...:)
1) How can I check it, if I have a public DNS wild.... ? I use aws ec2. I haven't setup by myself any additional DNS. Openshift has installed sth by itself. Problem may lay here. Could you point to some doc or tutorial on it?
2) By default generated hostname is blogroute-project-a.router.default.svc.cluster.local - it's not public name. To what hostname/ip should I set hostname? To public ip/ aws hostname of master node?

Comment: ``blogroute-project-a.router.default.svc.cluster.local`` is the service host name, it is not the generated route name. What instructions did you use to set up this cluster in the first place. If you run ``oc get routes`` does it display anything?

Comment: @Graham, I added current routes and services into description. This cluster was created in openshift webconsole, one application was deployed as source to image, and one as docker image from dockerhub. I am learning from https://learn.openshift.com/introduction/

Comment: Your cluster wasn't set up correctly. The exposed routes should not be using ``router.default.svc.cluster.local``.

Comment: So how should I set up a cluster? Do you know any very simple (foreducational purpose, not commercial) tutorial for creating open shift on aws?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by creating a load balancer with public IP and pointing it to all nodes at port 80 (haproxy is listening on port 80). Then you have to create a wildcard DNS, something like `*.apps.yourdomain.com`, and point that to the load balancer you created.

Afterwards you must configure your domain in the OpenShift cluster, see https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.6/install_config/install/advanced_install.html#configuring-cluster-variables.

Then you can expose your service and create a route, for example `blog.apps.yourdomain.com`.